# How to decode/display PLIST data from a MySQL field?

Tags: mysql, sql, plist

We have inherited a MySQL database that has plist formatted data saved in fields. I think the data was migrated from a SQLite db. Is there any way to decode that into a readable format in MySQL using a select statement? Or extract only specific fields of the plist data?

Comment: Maybe! But there's almost no way to answer this question as written, because you haven't shown a sample of the data, or what you want to extract from it. Also please show the table structure (use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`). The best would be to show a small reproducible sample using a DBFiddle. Finally, tell us what `SHOW VERSION();` reports from your MySQL instance, because the best solution might depend on features in a particular release of the product.